# How to use cloud.google.com/go/datastore with AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-golang

I'm migrating my Golang AppEngine app to 1.12+, and I need to switch to `cloud.google.com/go/datastore`. It's not clear to me how to use it with AppEngine, could someone please verify my assumptions?

My assumption is that somewhere inside `main()` I can run (note the `context.Background()`):

```
db, err := datastore.NewClient(context.Background(), datastore.DetectProjectID)
if err != nil {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    panic(err)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
defer db.Close()
```

And then from my handlers I can use that db:

```
func blah(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ctx := r.Context()
    key := datastore.NameKey("blah", blah, nil)
    db.Get(ctx, key, blah2)
}
```

Am I correct? Or do I need to run `datastore.NewClient()` separately from each web handler?

Comment: As per the [migration to App Engine Go app 1.12+ documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/go-differences), you can use [Datastore libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) in order to access the Datastore. Have a look at the documentation examples and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at mat ryers "hanger" approach. It allows you to initialize the dependencies once so your handlers don't have to. https://pace.dev/blog/2018/05/09/how-I-write-http-services-after-eight-years.html

Answer (score 0):

I run `datastore.NewClient()` for each web handler.  I only do this once for each web handler and only if that code needs to use the datastore.  Also, make sure that you `Close()` it at the end of your handler otherwise you'll leak memory.